# Not able to create Azure AD user account with Service Principle login using Python Automation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, user-accounts

I am writing an Python automation code for creating user account in Azure. I am able to do login with this code.

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli

get_default_cli().invoke(['login','--service-principal','-u','@*#*₹&@*@-269c-4fce-97f7-*******@*@&','-p','c0@*#L5oM&@₹₹"_@@~#@₹&~Kv42kZdfBA#**&@#*@SAp',
'--tenant', 'a@*#₹&@016-@#&537c-474*245628*#@38-9dasae-a0651d13₹@@#&*@79'])
```

But when I tried to create Azure user account with this service principal login I am getting "Insufficient Privileges to complete the operation" and not able to create user, and I have given all the permissions to that service principal.

Code for creating user account using Python.

```
get_default_cli().invoke(['ad', 'user', 'create','--user-principal-name', 'student6123@candlersstudent1gmail.onmicrosoft.com', '--display-name','student6123', 
    '--password','StudentP123@456'])
```

Is there something that I am missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to [assign a role to the service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application).

Then grant the Azure AD Graph Application permission `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to the service principal. (please note it's not Microsoft Graph permission)

[image]

[image]

Now you have the required permission to create an Azure AD user.